# Carousel transform with Bootstrap 4 Alpha on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, safari, transform, carousel

I had a problem with the Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5 Carousel component that seemed to occur only on iOS (10) Safari. For some reason, when sliding from one slide to another, the 'next' item that should come into view, did not slide in from the right or left, but instead popped into view after the slide was done. So it seemed like the element stayed hidden until after the slide completed. On desktop browsers, this problem did not appear at all.

After lots and lots of trying, I found that the problem had to do with the GPU hardware accelerated 3D transformations (transform-3d section of the Bootstrap CSS). When Googling for 'blink' and 'flicker', a lot of solutions point to either:

- using -webkit- prefixes
- adding `(-webkit-)backface-visibility: hidden;`
- adding `(-webkit-)perspective: 1000px;`
- adding `(-webkit-)transform: translateZ(0);`
- adding `(-webkit-)transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`
- adding `(-webkit-)transform-style: preserve-3d;`

However, non of these solutions (to initialize GPU rendering) solved my problem (completely), not when applying to (both) parent (.carousel-inner) and child (.carousel-item) elements. With some of them, the transformation itself seemed to go well, but the positioning of the child elements became incorrect.

Finaly, this page came to the rescue:

https://www.thecssninja.com/css/composited-layers-ios

So, what solved my problem was a combination of two things:

- Initiating the GPU on the parent element (.carousel-inner) by adding `-webkit-transform: scale(1);`
- Changing `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` on `'.carousel-inner > .next` and `.carousel-inner > .prev`

It took my hours to find this solution, so by posting this solution on StackOverflow I hope to help other developers having the same problem.

Any suggestions or recommendations are welcome!

**UPDATE**

Aparently I introduced myself a new problem with this solution, because now the position of the fixed (child) elements (sometimes) screws up when the carousel is scrolled off canvas... However, as soon as the next slide slides in, that slide does have the right position again. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is not a question, but a question + answer, right?

Comment: Well, it sort of is.. I introduced myself a new problem, because now the position of the fixed (child) elements (sometimes) screws up when the carousel is scrolled off canvas... I'll update my 'question'!

Comment: OK thanks, will do next time! For now, there's still a question left, so my initial question does not contain the (full) answer anymore...